# Would repeating random forest class prediction 1000 times and choosing most frequent class improve accuracy?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, predictive-models

[image]

I want to improve class prediction accuracy using random forest. I was wondering if I repeat the class prediction for each point 1000 times and choosing the most frequent answer make any sense (especially that the model itself has by default multiple iterations)?

Is there a way to choose the iteration that had highest accuracy compared to ground truth?

Here is a simple function to calculate accuracy of one iteration

```r
get_prediction <- function(x){
  
  random <- sample(1:nrow(iris), size=nrow(iris)*0.8, replace=FALSE)
  test <- iris[-random, ] %>% dplyr::select(-c(Species))
  train <- iris[random,]
  model <- randomForest::randomForest(formula=Species ~., data =train,
                  importance = TRUE )
  predict <- stats::predict(model, test, type="class")
  truth <- iris[-random,] %>% dplyr::pull(Species)
  return(round(sum(predict == truth)/length(truth)*100,2))
  
}


# here I repeat the function 1000 times


df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:1000, get_prediction)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  dplyr::rename_with(.cols=1, ~ "V1")


# plotting the total accuracy of each iteration

ggplot(df, aes(x=V1)) +
     geom_histogram(aes(y=after_stat(density)), alpha=0.3, fill="red",
                  linewidth=1, colour="black", bins=30) +
     geom_line(stat="density") +
     theme_cowplot(font_size=20) +
  xlim(0, 100) +
  labs(title="Accuracy", x="%", y="Density") +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste("Mean accuracy =", round(mean(V1),2), 
                        "%"), x=25, y=0.1), size=9)
```

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Isn’t this just a random forest with more trees in the forest?

Comment: @Dave mostly, but the majority vote of forests(' majority votes) needn't be the majority vote of the union of their trees.

Answer (score 2):

As @Dave suggests in the comments, the random forest algorithm is already creating many decision trees under the hood and letting them "vote" on which class should be chosen. Therefore, instead of iterating by hand, you can achieve the same solution by changing the size (number of decision trees) of the random forest.

> Is there a way to choose the iteration that had highest accuracy
> compared to ground truth?

I think this is an interesting question, but it cannot be done, because we do not know the "ground truth". What we have is a dataset, which is a sample from the entire population and the best we can do is to train a model on it without too much overfitting.

Let's say we proceeded like you suggest, created 1000 random forests and chose the one which scored the best on the `test set`, which is the closest to the "ground truth" we have. This would almost surely not help us, we would simply choose the random forest which by chance captures the quirks of the `test set` the best. However, there is no guarantee such a model would work well on new unseen data, which may not look so much like the `test data` which we used for model selection.

In general, random forests are good at preventing `overfitting`, since they create many slightly different trees which are averaged in the end. We do not find out which trees (or which forest) are the closest to ground truth, the best we can do is retrain the model again given new data.

Comment: After reading the comment by Ben Reiniger, I do not believe this to be correct.

Comment: @Dave I think I understand this could happen in close votes, but wouldn't this be irrelevant on average and thus not affect the quality of the final model? It seems to me bucketing a large forest into 1000 smaller ones should not make a difference, but I could be wrong.